# Jupyter Notebook : Change the size of the input box to default

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The default size of the input text field in my installation of Jupyter Notebook has doubled. I am not sure how it happened or how to get it back to the normal size. How can one reset the defaults ?

[image: Increased text box picture]

Answer (score 1):

For Jupyter notebook server is 4.2.1

Update `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` to add the following text:

```
/* Make the notebook cells take almost all available width */
.container {
    width: 99% !important;
}   

/* Prevent the edit cell highlight box from getting clipped;
 * important so that it also works when cell is in edit mode*/
div.cell.selected {
    border-left-width: 1px !important;
}
```